# TLC372 comparator setup

Tags: comparator

I am using a comparator Model [TLC372CP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc372.pdf) in following setup:
As the TLC has two comparators included, I am just using one of them.

[image: schematic]

If I am using the potentiometer, I can measure a dropping resistance at 1IN- so that depending on the poti position, sometimes 1IN+ is higher than 1IN- and sometime the other way around.

So I would expect 1OUT to change from LOW (0V) to HIGH (5V).
But I can not detect any change on 1OUT.

What is wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: The way that you've drawn the circuit the LED is the wrong way around.

Comment: Also, you have the battery +ve going to the comparators GND pin (pin 4) which is not going work.

Comment: If you build this circuit in the real world and the batteries were fresh enough, the opamp IC would be destroyed as you've reversed the supply voltage. There are only very few ICs that can survive that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned previously you have connected the battery the wrong way around and you may have damaged the comparator. Try the circuit below with a an unused IC.

Note that if you fit the LED and R3 you will not need R5. However, if you leave out the LED you will need R5. Most comparators have an open-collector output, (or for CMOS IC's an open-drain output). This type of output can only sink current, it cannot source current. An open drain output is often used with a pull-up resistor (R5) so that the output can both source and sink current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqHQyt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot - the missing R5 was the key for the solution (beside the wrong wiring or the wrong plan I have put together). The IC was still working but without R5 the comparator never changed - with R5 I get exatcly the expected result.